# Start alarm in broadcastreceiver and turn off in service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I think I have a design issue, but I will ask you guys the question.
My applications receives a broadcast in xbroadcastreceiver, i check some conditions and if true, I start a service, say zservice, using Alarm Manager with PendingIntent. Now in zservice, everytime when it is triggered by the alarmmanager, I check some other conditions and based upon a specific condition I need to cancel the alarm, I know alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
will cancel the alarm, but my issue is how to get a access to the pendingIntent as it was in the xbroadcastreciever.

I have tried send pendingIntent to service but so far I am not successful so that when I need, I can turn the alarm off.
Hope this logic makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent); will cancel the alram, but my issue is how to get a access to the pendingIntent as it was in the xbroadcastreciever.

Create an `Intent` with the same routing information (component, action, categories, MIME type) as the original. Create the same type of `PendingIntent` from this `Intent` as before (e.g., `getService()`). Use that `PendingIntent` with the `cancel()` call.

Comment: great :-)
funny what I didn't think could be the solution turned out be the case.
Thanks...